# How can i replace characters in a string using c#?

Tags: c#

I have a string

"This is a test string for testing in dotnet4.8 (.net)"   53 chars

The requirement is that if the length of the string is greater than 40 characters
then to replace characters with "" starting from the (.net) moving to the left until the total chars is 40  , so i will end up with

```
"This is a test string for testing (.net)"
```

and it doesnt matter if the word is cut off , cause there could be scneario where the string is different but they will always end in (.net)

Comment: What problems are you facing implementing it?

Comment: There are a couple of steps to this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts.  i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: One important information for beginners in C#. String cannot be changed. You can only create a new string based on something from existing strings. Having said that, there is a class `StringBuilder` that can be used to change the characters in a string (but inside there is no string, but an array of chars instead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want the actual text to be 34 letters long, so when adding your  "(.net)" ends up being 40.

so I guess something in the realms of:

```
public string Shorten(string s)
{
  if(s.Length > 40)
    return s.Substring(0,34) + "(.net)";
  else
    return s;
}
```

Comment: that works thanks.  I was trying to use for loops and move to the start position.This is cleaner.  I could also do this    s = (s.Length > 40) ?  s.Substring(0, 34) + " (.net)" : s;   ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const int maxLength = 40;
const string suffix = "(.net)";

var text = "This is a test string for testing in dotnet4.8 (.net)";
var exceed = text.Length - maxLength;
if (exceed > 0)
{
    text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - exceed - suffix.Length) + suffix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `Regex`:

```
var input = "This is a test string for testing in dotnet4.8 (.net)";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(.{0,34}).*?\(\.net\)$");
var result = $"{match.Groups[1].Value}(.net)";
```

That gives `This is a test string for testing (.net)`.